# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status from no such window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm accessing Selenium's `driver.title`. The follow exception occurred.

```
        File "features\steps\XXX_Admin_Edit_XXXXX_Steps.py", line 44, in <lambda>
          assert _wait_until(lambda: context.browser.get_title() == xxx_home.get_page_title(), HelperConstants.WAIT_ONE_MINUTE),\
        File "D:\c\behave-tests\2\_work\10\s\features\utilities\Browser.py", line 166, in get_title
          return self.driver.title
        File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 342, in title
          resp = self.execute(Command.GET_TITLE)
        File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
          self.error_handler.check_response(response)
        File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
          raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
      selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
      from no such window
        (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

I haven't reproduced the error, yet.

Google has almost no results for "cannot determine loading status from no such window"

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems you have versions incompatibility issue. Please check  `chromedriver` version supports the `chrome browser version` https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: @KunduK Our chromedriver matches the chrome version

Comment: Why this was closed as duplicate? The error message in the other topic relate to "cannot determine loading status from TAB CRASHED" whereas this topic is "cannot determine loading status from NO SUCH WINDOW"... These are different (albeit similar) issues that require different solutions. If you can't tell that, you shouldn't be moderating.